# how to obtain a specific http header in php

Tags: php, header

I need to get the value of a specific html header.
I can do it this way but it doesn't seem efficient and I'm hoping there is a  better way:

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
 if ($name == "My-Special-Header") { $headerValue = $value; }
}
```

Is there a better way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this any better: `$x=getallheaders();

echo $x['My-Special-Header'];`

Comment: They're called *http* headers not *html* headers which are like `<h3>`, `<h4>`.

Comment: Dagon ... yes that's better ... I tried something similar before asking but couldn't get the format correct.  If you turn it into an answer I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the header "My-Special-Header" would be accessible as

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_MY_SPECIAL_HEADER']);
```

Either way, check out the $_SERVER superglobal.

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

For my own recollection:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www# curl --header "My-Special-Header: Foobar" http://127.0.0.1/headers.php
<pre>Array
(
..
    [HTTP_MY_SPECIAL_HEADER] => Foobar
)
```

Comment: This is a special custom header and not one of the standard headers ... I don't see it included in the print_r($_SERVER); and therefore the var_dump brings back null.